# SignalR Dependency Injection for ASP.NET Core v2.0 using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-signalr

Is it possible to use dependency injection to inject dependencies into SignalR on ASP.NET Core v2.0?

Assuming the following hub and dependency:

```
public MyHub : Hub {

    private readonly IMyDependency dependency;

    public MyHub(IMyDependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}

public void MyDependency : IDependency
{
    public void MyMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a dependency!");
    }
}
```

I've scoured a bit of the web and there isn't anything obvious out there.  I [found this tutorial](https://geeks.ms/clanderas/2016/11/03/asp-net-core-with-signalr-server-and-autofac/) which at first seemed quite promising until I realised it was for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server` which didn't ship in the end.

At the moment I have the following setup using Autofac and it's not working:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSignalR();

        // Configue Autofac
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();

        // Configure SignalR hubs for dependency injection
containerBuilder.RegisterSignalRHubs(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }
}

public static class AutoFacExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<object, ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle> RegisterSignalRHubs(this ContainerBuilder builder, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        return builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => typeof(IHub).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ExternallyOwned();
    }
}

public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyDependency>().As<IMyDependency>();
    }
}
```

It looks like the `IHub` interface doesn't exist anymore.  I tried `IHubContext<MyHub>` in the hope that this might work with the latest version but sadly not.

When I have dependencies in my hub's constructor, the hub isn't created <s>despite all of the dependencies registered with Autofac</s>.

How can I achieve this with the lastest version `1.0.0.0-alpha2-final`?

Comment: As much as it pains me to admit this, I was simply missing a registration for some of my dependencies - this is working with `Hub` instead of `IHub`.  I was able to find out they weren't registered by assigning my `IDependency` to a Controller constructor instead of the Hub and then the error was obvious.  This is indeed a way that can be used to use DI with SignalR (the current version at time of writing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example given in the question does work with version `1.0.0.0-alpha2-final` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` with one slight tweak, use `Hub` rather than the now non-existent `IHub`.

```
public static class AutoFacExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<object, ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle> RegisterSignalRHubs(this ContainerBuilder builder, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        // typeof(Hub), not typeof(IHub)
        return builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => typeof(Hub).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ExternallyOwned();
    }
}
```

Ensure that all of your dependencies are satisfied by assigning them to a controller.  I'm not sure at this point how to troubleshoot broken dependencies when injecting into a SignalR hub with this method.

Comment: SignalR only injects dependencies if the Hubs are registered in the container.